# how to find docker 1.3.1 rpm at epel

Tags: docker, centos6.5

I want to install docker 1.3.1 on my centos 6.5 environment but I have no idea how to find it in the epel. I'm quite new to docker. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly stated in [the Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/):

> Docker runs on CentOS 7.X.

CentOS 6.5 is not CentOS 7.X. Docker is not available for your old operating system.

Furthermore, you didn't give any details about your computer, but you should remain aware that Docker only works on 64-bit systems.

By the way, you should take better care of your computer; in CentOS, the minor version number is updated automatically by the package manager. So the fact that you are two versions behind (CentOS 6 is currently on 6.7) indicates that you are not performing updates to your packages, and could have various security vulnerabilities. You should update your system regularly, by simply running `yum update`.